# Can there be a relation "one-many" between NFT?

Tags: nft

...as in one NFT is a parent one and the others are its children. Think of "object" and its "attributes" relation. Or a soldier and weapons, clothes and other things he could possess.

Is this possible in the NFT world? If so, how would I work with it on the programming level? E.g.

- create/mint a parent NFT
- establish a possible set of its children/attributes
- bind together parent and children
  add/remove those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, for sure. NFT can contain many properties and attributes. Even mappings to other NFT's and such.

You can also create functions that allow you to modify/delete those attributes.

However, something like that might be quite expensive to mint on a public chain.

```
Here is example of SmartContract similar to what you requested:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";

contract SoldierItems is ERC1155 {
    uint256 public constant SOLDIER = 0;
    uint256 public constant WEAPON = 1;
    uint256 public constant ARMOR = 2;

    struct SoldierAttributes {
        uint256[] weapons;
        uint256[] armors;
    }

    mapping (uint256 => SoldierAttributes) private _soldierAttributes;

    constructor() public ERC1155("https://game.example/api/item/{id}.json") {
        _mint(msg.sender, SOLDIER, 1, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, WEAPON, 10, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, ARMOR, 5, "");
    }

    // This function can be called to assign a weapon to a soldier
    function assignWeapon(uint256 soldierId, uint256 weaponId) public {
        // Check that the caller owns the soldier and the weapon NFT
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender, SOLDIER) > 0, "Caller does not own the soldier NFT");
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender, WEAPON) >= weaponId, "Caller does not own the weapon NFT");

        // Assign the weapon to the soldier
        _soldierAttributes[soldierId].weapons.push(weaponId);
    }

    // This function can be called to assign an armor to a soldier
    function assignArmor(uint256 soldierId, uint256 armorId) public {
        // Check that the caller owns the soldier and the armor NFT
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender, SOLDIER) > 0, "Caller does not own the soldier NFT");
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender, ARMOR) >= armorId, "Caller does not own the armor NFT");

        // Assign the armor to the soldier
        _soldierAttributes[soldierId].armors.push(armorId);
    }

    // Call to get the weapons of a soldier
    function getWeaponsOfSoldier(uint256 soldierId) public view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        return _soldierAttributes[soldierId].weapons;
    }

    // Call to get the armors of a soldier
    function getArmorsOfSoldier(uint256 soldierId) public view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        return _soldierAttributes[soldierId].armors;
    }
}
```

NOTE: I used ERC-1155 (NFT standard that allows you to use handle many different NFT's in same contract)

In short: It's surely possible. But do consider the cost of it.

Comment: Ok, how would I do it, in a simple way?

Comment: @Camila326 do you need some simple code example? What example would you like? Solder and attributes, weapons,  etc?

Comment: @Camila326 I added code example.